# File upload to remote server using php without form post / cURL POST method

Tags: php

Is there any possibility to place zip files from local machine to server location.

Without using FTP, FORM POST/ cURL POST.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're avoiding POST/cURL POST?

Comment: It's a too big file like 500-MB sized files. The through PHP it's a big truble.

Comment: also rsync can be used

Comment: Yeah correct through ssh ftp we can achieve this

Comment: read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
       $connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
       ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

       ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/local/filename', '/remote/filename', 0644);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use ssh. scp can move file from your machine to server.